# An issue with context on jquery waypoints post

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints, .post

I have set up waypoints to do a json post when triggered, however the webserver never recieves the request. I get the following jquery error.

TypeError: context is null
http://mysite
Line 5082

I know the waypoints are messing with the context, because I can perform the post call if I remove the waypoints.
I have also tried removing all data and success actions.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.product_row').waypoint(getDisplayRow);
});
function getDisplayRow()
{
    var search_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    var codes = [];
    $(this.element).children().each(function() {
        codes.push($(this).attr('product_id'));
    });
    $.post('/ajax/getproductdisplayrow/', {codes: codes,
        subcategory_url: $('#subcategory_url').val(),
        category_url: $('#category_url').val(),
        show_color_squares: $('#show_color_squares').val(),
        search_url: search_url
    }, function(data) {
            $(this.element).before(data); 
            $(this.element).remove();
            adjustRowHeight();
    });
}
```

This doesn't work either

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.product_row').waypoint(getDisplayRow);
});
function getDisplayRow()
{
    $.post('/ajax/getproductdisplayrow/', {
    }, function(data) {
    });
}
```

I have latest version of waypoints, as well as jquery

Answer (score 0):

In your callback to the POST:

```
function(data) {
  $(this.element).before(data); 
  $(this.element).remove();
  adjustRowHeight();
});
```

`this` is no longer the Waypoint instance. I believe it is the jqXHR instance from the post. `this.element` comes back undefined and who knows what happens from there when you try to call `before`. You can store this element property in a variable within the outer function and use it inside the POST callback:

```
function getDisplayRow()
{
  var search_url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
  var codes = [];
  var $waypointElement = $(this.element);
  $waypointElement.children().each(function() {
    codes.push($(this).attr('product_id'));
  });
  $.post('/ajax/getproductdisplayrow/', {codes: codes,
    subcategory_url: $('#subcategory_url').val(),
    category_url: $('#category_url').val(),
    show_color_squares: $('#show_color_squares').val(),
    search_url: search_url
  }, function(data) {
    $waypointElement.before(data); 
    $waypointElement.remove();
    adjustRowHeight();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried that. I also tried passing in the element to getDisplayRow. That didn't work either.